# Nginx proxypass all the traffic except some that follows a particular URL pattern

Tags: nginx

I am running an app in a docker container with nginx in front as a load-balancer. I would like to pass all the traffic to the app except one with following URL pattern

```
https://mydomain/peek/somepage.php
```

The following nginx config renders https://mydomain/peek/somepage.html from the folder `peek` but not `somepage.php` because I don't know how to write configuration for fastcgi to process the php files in this particular location.

```
upstream discourse {
 server 127.0.0.1:8080;
 }

location ^~ /peek {
        alias /home/forge/domain_name/public/peek;
}

location / {
         include proxy_params;
         proxy_pass http://discourse;
         proxy_redirect off; proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664872/configuring-nginx-to-return-a-404-when-a-url-matches-a-pattern).

```
location /mydomain/peek/somepage.php {
  return 404;
}
```